# How do I programatically start an internet connection?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, systems-programming

I want to programmatically start broadband (PPOE) internet connection.

I'm not sure if [InternetDial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384587%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will work as the documentation clearly says that it initiates a connection to the Internet using a modem.

I tried searching for the API function but I couldn't find one.

I am trying to create a program that will take a user name and password and then connect to the internet. Similar to this program.

[image]

Right now I just need the name of API function as I want to implement this program on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: You could investigate the [`RasDialDlg` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377020.aspx). I'm not really sure if it works for PPPoE connections. Seems the best way to find out is to try it yourself. (But uh, why reinvent the wheel? It seems Windows already provides this functionality...)

Comment: @Cody Gray Just for learning purpose. I want to be a system programmer and sometimes I find it hard to understand the MSDN documentation. I thought may be I'll get use to the documentation style after reading windows architecture and trying out some basic examples first. Thanks : )

Comment: Fair enough. The best way to understand the MSDN documentation for the Windows API is to already know what it's telling you. ;-) There's no substitute for experience.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> InternetOpen
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385096(VS.85).aspx

or

> InternetGoOnline
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384734(VS.85).aspx